# how to authenticate user and admin with the same login form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I have created a  user authentication using devise in rails app .Now i have to create a new model for Admin.i can do that by either creating a new admin model(devise) or write roles in user model like

example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 enum :roles[:admin,:superadmin]
end
```

but how should I login as admin when  without creating another SIGNUP OR LOGIN form.or if i create a diffrent  regestration and login for admin how can I hide that from users.Inshort i need to create a admin panel and dashbord for admin and need some authorizations.iam new to rails plz help.also you can suggest me another approch for doing it (i dont want selec box or checkbox in my login for roles because anyone can become admin then)

EDIT:

I want to know about the authentication for admin and user ,authorization is the next part .if i create a diffrent admin registration form any user can come and become admin.what will be the other approch?.

Comment: The syntax for your `enum` statement is not correct and would raise an error, and you probably want the column name to be `role` instead of `roles`. it should be `enum role: [:admin, :superadmin]`, and even better would be `enum role: { admin: 0, superadmin: 1 }`. read this article for more explanation https://bendyworks.com/blog/rails-enum-sharp-knife

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can make additional model `Role` which will be `[admin, superadmin, user]` and will be related to `User`. 
let's say user can have only one role (`has_one`) so when user is created you should assign a particular role to him. This way you can simply use:
`current_user.role.name #=> "admin"`

Good practice is to implement methods in `User` class:

```
def admin?
  role.name == "admin"
end

def user?
  role.name == "user"
end
```

So you can simply call: `current_user.admin?`.

I suggest you to use some `authorization` library, for restricting/allowing access to diff parts on your application.

There is a plenty of them, like Pundit, CanCan etc ...

Hope this will help you to start, then you will see how many options you have ;)

### Update:

You're assigning role to user during registration process, or via admin panel later.

About register form, you will have `RegistrationController` which is overridden from Devise so you can simply put `user.role = Role.find_by_name("user")` before creating user.

This is default role for all users who are registered via register form. But, you will have some admin dashboard where you can change role for users and assign to them maybe to be moderator, admin, superadmin etc..

About login form, there is no need to assign role but just to get `current_user` and to get his role.

Let's say you have 2 different navigations for `user` & `admin`. When user is successfully logged in, in you application.html.erb layout you can do simply check :

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
 <%= render "navigation/admin_navigation" %>
<% elsif current_user.user? %>
 <%= render "navigation/user_navigation" %>
<% end %>
```

This way you will show appropriate navigation, so this is *authorization on view level*.

You can also have *authorization logic on controller level*, for certain actions:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin, only: [:index]

  private
  def authorize_admin
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Permissions denied" unless
     current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

This way you're allowing ONLY admin to access to `Posts#index`.

Hope it's more clear now :)
Cheers

Comment: thank you man.but if i have a simple single login form how can roles be assigned automatically as a admin or user?can you plz exaggerate especially the view part?

Comment: your are very close to the answer but can you plz clarify what i need to do in my registration controller so that i can register admin and user from same form.or else i need another form for registration for admin.is the above answer is by considering that we have a new model as ROLE?

Comment: @zauzaj why is another model preferable to `enum role: [:admin, :user]`? this usage of `enum` would give you all of these methods for free: `user.user?`, `user.user!`, `user.admin?`, `user.admin!`, `User.user`, `User.admin`

Comment: @AaquibKhan you don't need another form, but same one as admin have totally the same attributes as user but different role. I'm not sure about your business logic, but mostly cases admin is first user or it's created from seed. That's because you need someone who will manage other users. That's why I told, on registration form you only set `user` role -> then you manage that user and change role if needed.

Comment: @AaquibKhan I think there is no sense that user can register and to become `admin` automatically. Case with 2 different forms as per roles is maybe, `Upwork` -> `Register as Freelancer/Register as Client` then you have 2 diff forms with diff fields where one set freelancer role and another one client role

Comment: @m.simonborg I didn't say it's better, I just put such approach as I like to have more flexibility for later purposes, especially if you would need to add some additional roles or maybe multiple roles to user ;)

Comment: cool! if using `enum` properly (hash of enums instead of array) adding additional roles is not a problem, but definitely a model gives you the flexibility to have many roles. Asking b/c the OP started with `enum` and I think if you offer a different approach (one that requires migrations, associations, custom method definitions and extra database hits) it would be good to explain the reason why : ) nice answer btw!

Comment: @m.simonborg I agree with you, but I'm lack in time atm , so I wanted to focus on concrete problem. This authorization question is quite big topic & I'd like to discuss about best approaches btw :)

Comment: @zauzaj thats what i wanted bro, but how to put the admin credentials in seed that is issue now .sorry iam totally new to raills but your answer is right as what i wanted.

Comment: @AaquibKhan you can do something like:
`Role.create(name: 'admin'); User.create(email: "admin@khan.com, password: "password10", role_id: Role.find_by_name("admin"));`

You can try in rails console first, but be sure that you configured all relationships properly. Then you will setup admin user and you can use him ;)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple would be to create column for example "admin" type boolean in user model and based on that make permissions to administration.

You can create permisson check in application_controller.rb like this

```
  def check_admin
    unless current_user.admin
        redirect_to '/', :alert => "Don't have permission!"
    end
  end
```

And use it in controller for actions only admin can make like this:

```
before_action :check_admin, only: [:edit, :create]
```

For more scurity use separate models for User and Admin with separate routes and view for Public and Admin users.

Answer (score 0):

It is not direct answer to your question, but read some info on STI - single table inheritance.

And wherever you need special behavior for the admin you can just check if user type is admin

Comment: can someone explain me from model to view full approch as iam struct

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is to add a role column on the users table and check the value, for example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def role
    super.try(:inquiry)
  end
end

user.role.admin?
```

It depends on your needs, do you really need a `Role` model or a separate `User` and `Admin` model. Do you need to know any more than is this user an admin, if not, this is an easy and simple solution.